# Concurrency in Java(FX)

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx

In my JavaFX application I want to display an intermediate ProgressIndicator, while loading data from a database for instance. I tried to solve this problem by setting a different fxml-file (indicator.fxml), containing a ProgressIndicator with intermediate property, into the main BorderPane. And after that, setting the desired Stage into the BorderPane.

The indicator.fxml gets displayed, but seems to be frozen, because it is not animating. PersondataController controller = loader.getController() takes some time to be finished.

```
@FXML
private void showPersonData(){
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader();
        loader2.setLocation(RootLayoutController.class.getResource("Indicator.fxml"));
        AnchorPane progress = loader2.load();
        mainApp.getRootLayout().setCenter(progress);´

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(RootLayoutController.class.getResource("Persondata.fxml"));
                PersondataController controller = loader.getController();

                AnchorPane page = null;
                try {
                    page = loader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mainApp.getRootLayout().setCenter(page);
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If loading `Persondata.fxml` takes a long time, for some reason, you need to execute it in a background thread, instead of on the FX Application Thread. Also, as an aside, you need to call `loader.getController()` after you call `loader.load()`. It will just return `null` the way you are calling it.

Comment: Thank you James_D. But how can I achieve the background thread? Isn't that already done with Platform.runLater()....?

Comment: No, `Platform.runLater()` explicitly runs the code on the FX Application Thread (read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)). Use a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and either wrap it in a thread or execute in an `Executor` (again, see the docs). However, it's really unusual for an `FXMLLoader` to take a long time to load. Why is this happening in this case?

Comment: [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) does the exact opposite of what you currently think it does user3006108.  It will "Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future.", not run the logic on a background thread.   To understand how to use background threads and have them interact with your JavaFX API, then read [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317787/concurrency-in-javafx)

Comment: My guess is that is the database load which is taking a long time, not the FXML loading per-se.  Perhaps the user has written some database logic in the initialize function of his FXML controller.

Comment: Yes its that database-load which is taking that long.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved my problem with your help. thank you guys.

Instead of the Platform.runLater() stuff I did:

```
Service<Void> backgroundThread = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader();
                        loader2.setLocation(RootLayoutController.class.getResource("Persondata.fxml"));
                        PersondataController = loader2.getController();
                        page = loader2.load();
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        backgroundThread.setOnSucceeded((evt) -> {
            mainApp.getRootLayout().setCenter(page);
        });
        backgroundThread.start();
```